# Cutting a $D$-dimensional space with $n$ hyperplanes

Tags: geometry

I'm wondering the following: **What's the maximum number of parts you can get when cutting a $D$-dimensional space with $n$ hyperplanes?** The root of this questioning is that I first dicovered while studying simple neural nets for classification, that in 2D with 3 binary output neurons, where the network is just a linear classificator (no hidden layer), you can get maximum 7 classes, and not 8 (number of possible combinations of 3 binary digits) as expected.

[image: Results from a linear classificator]

As shown on the image, the class 010 is missing. There can also be the case where all three points intersect at the same place and we only get 6 domains but this is of fewer interest for me.

---

I've tried to understand what's going on in two dimensions and I figured out that you can get maximum $n+1$ new domains by adding a straight line, where $n$ designs the number of existing straight lines. It seems to work pretty fine, although I did not prove it (my bad):

For all integer $n$, let $f(n)$ be the maximum number of domains that you can get with $n$ straight lines on a plane.

$$
\text{Conjecture:}~~~~~~~~~~~\begin{cases}
f(0)=1\\
\forall n>0, ~~ f(n)=n+f(n-1)
\end{cases}
$$

Then I tried to see how the problem looked like in higher dimensions, starting with planes in 3D but it quickly became hard to sketch on a sheet of paper. I defined another function $f_D$ that describes the maximum number of domains you get when cutting a $D$-dimensional space with hyperplanes. From hand drawings, I got the following formula (which does not hold for $n=0$ anymore):

$$
\text{Conjecture:}~~~~~~~~~~~\forall D\in \mathbb N^*, ~~ \begin{cases}
f_D(1)=2\\
\forall n>1, ~~ f_D(n)=n\cdot(D-1)+f(n-1)
\end{cases}
$$

Which can be de-recursified (easy proof by induction) into:

$$
\forall D, n\in \mathbb N^*, f_D(n)=\frac{n^2+n-2}{2}(D-1)+2 = \frac{n\cdot(n+1)}{2}(D-1)+3-D
$$

---

Can anyone *prove* or *disprove* my intuition? Or give me hints about how I should take the problem, or point me to existing solutions? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The maximum number of regions is
$$\binom{n}{0}+\binom{n}{1}+\binom{n}{2}+\cdots+\binom{n}{D}.$$
When you introduce the $(n+1)$-th hyperplane $H$, the maximal number of
new regions introduces is when $H$ is sliced into $f_{D-1}(n)$ regions
by the first $n$ hyperplanes so that
$$f_D(n+1)=f_D(n)+f_{D-1}(n).$$

Comment: Looks amazing, and way prettier thatn my original formula! But I need time to try and digest that ;)